# SQL reverse id column values

Tags: mysql

I recently imported an excel arch into an sql database. The values imported look like:

```
name     age   adress       date
carl     12    something    2015-11-10
lisa     51    something2   2+15-10-09
steven   32    something3   2014-12-29
```

I then added an auto increment column named id, which resulted in:

```
id    name    age   adress       date
1     carl    12    something    2015-11-10
2     lisa    51    something2   2+15-10-09
3     steven  32    something3   2014-12-29
```

My problem is that I need to reverse the ids. Because if I now where to insert a new row, it'd result in the date column not matching up with the id column. It'd look like this:

```
id    name    age   adress       date
1     carl    12    something    2015-11-10
2     lisa    51    something2   2015-10-09
3     steven  32    something3   2014-12-29
4     neil    25    something4   2016-01-12
```

I've searched for methods of creating a new id column, reversed. Or reversing my existing column. Problem is I haven't succeeded very well.

Comment: what's the point of reversing the id column?

Comment: The `date` column can be used to `ORDER BY` date, and the `id` column can be used as a primary key.  Is there some other need you have?

Comment: Now thinking about it, I guess you might be right. There's no need to order by id, rather I can do it using the date. Thanks!

Comment: I am very curious what you are doing where this matters.  Best practice with autoincrement integers is to be a unique record label (a primary key).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new empty table also with autoincremt and insert the rows in reverse order

```
INSERT into new_table
 select '',name,age address,`date`
  FROM org_table
  ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Comment: I suppose this technically answers the question, even though it would be pointless to do.

Comment: Although it may be pointless for the OP, I am glad someone answered the basic question since in my case it is not pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Old topic but if anyone else is looking for an answer, here's what I found to do this:

```
SELECT MAX(id) as max_id FROM table;
```

Get this max_id value (example: 28542)

Ensure you that your "id" column is not UNSIGNED, otherwise, uncheck "Unsigned" param in your table structure mysql. And then:

```
UPDATE table SET id=(id - max_id) * (-100000);
example: UPDATE table SET id=(id - 28542) * (-100000);
```

And

```
UPDATE table SET id=(id/100000);
```

Results, before:

```
id    name    age   adress       date
1     carl    12    something    2015-11-10
2     lisa    51    something2   2015-10-09
3     steven  32    something3   2014-12-29
```

After:

```
id        name    age   adress       date
28541     carl    12    something    2015-11-10
28540     lisa    51    something2   2015-10-09
28539     steven  32    something3   2014-12-29
```

So the new record will be

```
28542     neil    25    something4   2016-01-12
```