# Reorder MariaDB table to ascending

Tags: mariadb

I want to reserve the order of a MariaDB table.  I actually want the table to change not just output the data  in reverse order.

So I want the row at position 1 to move to the end and the row at the end to move to position one ect.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM wp_posts' at line 1

Comment: What does this have to do with reordering the table? If you want to change the next ID assigned using `AUTO_INCREMENT`, you do that with `ALTER TABLE`.

Comment: @Barmar can you post an example, I want to reverse the table order

Comment: Did you mean to say "reverse the order"?

Comment: The concept of `reordering` a DB is a wrong mistake. The DB rows are not ordered (at least in the way you expect). A table is an unordered set of rows, so if I don´t understand wrong, what you are trying to do makes non sense in a DB. If you want to get your result in a reverse order, just use `ORDER BY XXX DESC`, but the phisical order of the table does not depend on the order you insert rows (or any other similar thing), depends on the server, HD, DB, table, etc state in the moment you do the insert

Comment: @Barmar you're right the method I was trying makes no sense.  I want the table's rows to be in reverse order.

Comment: @Barmar but I want to change the table not just output the data in reverse order.  So the row at position 1 will switch it's ID with the row at the last position ect.

Comment: @Barmar is there a way to replace the table with a reordered version?

Comment: insert select to temporary table order by id desc, drop table, rename temporary table - nb I think this may be a duplicate..https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97277/reverse-auto-increment-id-existing-column-in-phpmyadmin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL reverse id column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34736272/sql-reverse-id-column-values)

Comment: again, rows do *not* have any stored order.  you are having some problem that leads you to think you want to change the table to reverse the order; show what *that* problem is.  show what are you trying to do that you want to change the results of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `SELECT` query to return `COUNT(*)`:

```
SET @total = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_posts)
```

To renumber the IDs, you need to do it in two steps, so you don't get duplicates during the process. First renumber everything outside the original range. You also need to use `MAX(id)` rather than `COUNT(*)`, because if any records have been deleted the count will be lower than the maximum ID.

```
SET @offset = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM wp_posts);
UPDATE wp_posts SET id = @offset + id;
```

Then renumber them back into the original range:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET id = @offset - (id - @offset);
```

Comment: Now I get `Duplicate entry '803' for key 'PRIMARY'`

Comment: I've updated the answer to do it in two steps to prevent duplication.

Comment: Probably worth noting if they `wp_posts.id` had a relationship to any other tables there are now totally jumbled. Hence renumbering generally is a way to break things, potentially your client/employment relationship.

Comment: Foreign keys should have `ON UPDATE CASCADE` so they'll be kept in sync. I assume WordPress does this right.